# Terminal: user and computer id tag incorrect

Tags: terminal

After trying ZORIN linux OS on my Mac mini as stand alone, then restoring big sur, the terminal shows this line instead of the expected apple or Mac reference:

Last login: Tue May 11 16:00:33 on ttys000
loz@zorin ~ %

I tried renaming the computer in Preferences, Sharing, to no avail.

Comment: Excuse my bad manners:  "Hello"

Comment: The issue is resolved, thank you.